# Check if user input are in the comboBox items

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, validating

This is how I check if a user input a empty in comboBox

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox.Text))
{
MessageBox.Show("No Item is Selected"); 
}
```

How to check if user input are in the comboBox items? For example  the comboBox items are a,b,c. When the user input "d" in the comboBox then he leaves, a messageBox must show.

Comment: What do you mean by "User input d in the combobox" ?

Comment: add a lostfocus event for each element in the combobox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try putting something like this in your ComboBox's Leave EventHandler as George stated, checking if the item is contained in the ComboBox's Item Collection.

```
private void comboBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
    if (! cb.Items.Contains(cb.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No Item is Selected");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int resultIndex = -1;
resultIndex = comboBox.FindExactString("d");

if(resultIndex == -1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("No Item is Selected");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the answer from @Mark Hall is correct. But if you want to restrict the user to not use a item which isn't in the item collection from the combo box, I suggest you to turn the the property of DropDownStyle to DropDownList.

```
comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```